# Custom look and feel without inheritance

Tags: java, swing, look-and-feel

How can I make my own look and feel without inheriting any previous look and feel? I know that it's like "re-inventing the wheel" but I don't actually like any of the existing **free** look and feels. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Don't reinvent the wheel. You should at least use Basic L&F UIs. For example `MyTextFieldUI extends BasicTextFieldUI`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've done a laf (http://nilogonzalez.es/nimrodlf/index.html) and, well, if you want to write a laf from scratch you have my respect...

The best approach is to extend Metal classes. That way you will get a lot of work done and a bunch of hints of what to do. You will get a lot of components that paint a rectangle and handle events, so to do your laf you "just" have to change the paint* method to paint your laf, but you save an enormous amount of work.

If you want to make your laf without using Metal as basement you will have to do... Well, look at the javadoc to figure the size of your project...

I recomend you to get the Kunststoff sources (http://kunstoff.incors.com/) to take a look of what you have to do. Kunststoff is enough simple to get an idea of what to do, and is very candy even in components that simple have a few lines of code.

Comment: Oh. Thank you so much!